# MySQL Workbench expecting command between table name and columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, insert-into

I'm using MySQL Workbench, as part of automating adding and updating information to my table I'm using a statement like the following.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(ID,Name,Location) VALUES (1232346, 'Bob', 'France')
```

I've been looking at the reference manual online for my version of the program (5.6.15) and according to that there shouldn't be need for anything additional in my statement. But when I put it into the SQL query it gives me an error at the first bracket that...

> "(" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: VALUE, SELECT, SET, VALUES, WITH

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't suppose that your version of MySQL requires a space here: `table_name (ID,`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were two things wrong with my original.
The first was that there was a typo with one of my column names.
The second was that there was a different number of columns and values that I had given.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [manual for insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html), use a space after the table name:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (ID,Name,Location)
VALUES (1232346, 'Bob', 'France')
```

Comment: Whether there is a space or not doesn't seem to make a difference to the error

Answer (score 0):

May be the ID column is an autoincrement column and should not be explicitly assigned?
Have you tried

INSERT INTO table_name(Name,Location) VALUES ('Bob', 'France')

Comment: ID isn't an auto-increment column but i removed it anyway and it still gave me the original error